# Can't understand the error with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a todoList and I'm understanding the process of localstorage, so i tried adding default items in my todoList

```
var bla = "[{text: 't1', key: 1602048390632}, {text: 't2', key: 1602048392604}, {text: 't3', key: 1602048393953}]"; 
   
   this.state = { 
    items:  JSON.parse(bla)
   };
```

But here It shows a cross origin that react doesn't have access to show.
The output I need is t1, t2, t3.
The CORS error

```
 ReactDOM.render(
   <div>
    <TodoList/>
      </div>,
```

Comment: You sample data here is not valid JSON, so this alone will cause errors in your code. As for a CORS-issue, there is not enough information here to actually help you.

Comment: Your string is not a valid JSON. Where did you got that data? Fix it's syntax to `'[{"text": "t1", "key": 1602048390632}, {"text": "t2", "key": 1602048392604}, {"text": "t3", "key": 1602048393953}]'`

Comment: That is json inside a list

Comment: you may wanna add the code which is throwing the **CORS** error as you mentioned in OP

Comment: @Sirko Cool, I'll check around, thanks

Comment: added @sandeepjoshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `JSON.parse` for `bal` variable because the key is not covered with double quotes("").

In this case, you can use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

```js
var bla = "[{text: 't1', key: 1602048390632}, {text: 't2', key: 1602048392604}, {text: 't3', key: 1602048393953}]"; 
   
const state = { 
  items: eval(bla)
};
console.log(state);
```

Comment: Yaa eval is working but It says it's harmful, still thanks for the answer @Derek.W